# How do I access stored accounts on an Android device in MAUI?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm building a MAUI app where I'd like to check if a user is signed in to a specific email address on his device. In Xamarin Forms, this used to be possible using the AccountManager class, but I can't find anything similar in MAUI. Does anyone have any idea how I could do that?

Code sample of how I tried it:

```
 var emails = new List<string>();

        var manager = Android.Accounts.AccountManager.Get(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity);
        var accounts = manager.GetAccounts();
        foreach(var acc in accounts) {
            emails.Add(acc.Name);
        }
```

The emails list as well as accounts returns empty.

Thanks!

Comment: You can still use the AccountManager class in the maui project.

Comment: I've tried, but I get 0 accounts returned with it. I'll add a code snippet if you maybe know what's wrong

Comment: Can you make sure you should have a return value when you can the method?

Comment: I placed a breakpoint and it showed an empty array after...